# Transform Query In Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query in MYSQL with PHP:

```
SELECT `ALUMNO`, `ID`, `ASIGNATURA`, `PERIODO1`, `PERIODO2`,
        `PERIODO3`, `PERIODO4`, `DEFINITIVA`
 FROM `temp_informeconsolidadoalumno`

ALUMNO, ID, ASIGNATURA, P1, P2, P3, P4, DEF
--------------------------------------------
000022, 22, TEST_TEST-, 02, 01, 85, 66, 52
```

But i need transform in this with MYSQL:

```
ALUMNO     000022
ID         22
ASIGNATURA TEST_TEST-
P1         02
P2         01
P3         85
P4         66   
DEF        52
```

The subjects as columns and periods as rows.

Please, i need help for do a query that allows me to do this.

Comment: Are you doing this interactively in the MySQL monitor? You can get output like that by ending the query with `\G`.

Comment: Initially thanks for answer and sorry for my english.  I'm building a report in PDF but the data should display like this: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uMxRYBM713ZkwwLUcyclBLYTg&authuser=0) and data in my database is so [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uMxRYBM713MjRuTE9MMnJiVEE&authuser=0) for this reason I need tranform query.

Comment: There's no general way to transpose rows and columns in MySQL like that. If you're using a programming language to process the query results, you can do it there.

Comment: If you're loading the data into a spreadsheet, it may have a transpose function.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i'm not using spreadsheet, i'm using a library FPDF and is a little limited. But i will follow you indications and i'll do it directly in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `union all`:

```
SELECT 'ALUMNO' as Col, ALUMNO as Val FROM temp_informeconsolidadoalumno
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ID', ID FROM temp_informeconsolidadoalumno
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASIGNATURA', ASIGNATURA FROM temp_informeconsolidadoalumno
...
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0f45b/3)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to transform this way [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uMxRYBM713ZkwwLUcyclBLYTg&authuser=0). My data is this: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uMxRYBM713MjRuTE9MMnJiVEE&authuser=0)